# Is it possible to get current selected text in Playwright JS select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, select, dropdown, playwright

I can set value in the select dropdown. But when I call textContent, it returns all options values.
My task is to verify that the set value is selected properly by extracting the value and checking it.

Is there any support for it in Playwright JS?

I tried different solutions.

One of them is below, but it didn't work

```
const selectedOptionText = await page.$eval(
  `${selector_value_here} option:checked`,
  (option) => option.textContent
);

console.log('Selected option text:', selectedOptionText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you can do like below:

```
await expect(page.locator('option[selected="selected"]')).toHaveText('Option 1');
```

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/discussions/11472

Comment: Thank you so much. Since I don't have selected option, this approach didd't work. 
But I found the solution in the reference link.

Answer (score 0):

You may use evaluate
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/next/api/class-worker#worker-evaluate

> locator.evaluate("el => el.options[el.selectedIndex].text")